# unbind the initial click function on another button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a form which is initially hidden. 
There is two steps of click flow to reach the form. I need to reset the initial click action when the form close button is clicked.

Adding the sample code and demo.

Here goes the flow

- Click on the `Join Now` text
- Then click on the text `Click here to open the form` text
- Then click on the `close` icon
- There comes the pop up

What I now need to know is,

1. By clicking on `Yes` , the form needs to be reset and the screen should look like how it looked initially (Brand name box with `join now` text) and the initial click action of `join now` should be refreshed.
2. By clicking on `No`, it should remain on the same form.

   ```
      $(".button").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).hide();
           $(".slidethis").fadeIn(800).css("display","inline-block");
           $(".wrapper").css("display","block");
       });

     $(".seconddiv").hide();
       //forstdiv click 
       $(".firstdiv").click(function(){        
           $(this).hide();
           $(".seconddiv").show();
       });

       //Close button 
       $(".close_icon").click(function(){      
           $(".popup").show();
       });
   ```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5353ntuf/2/)**

*P.S: I don't want to refresh the page by closing the form.*

Comment: The easiest way i know to remove an event function is to use a named function and jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/): `selection.on('click', myNamedFunction);` then `selection.off('click', myNamedFunction);`

Comment: That sounds like a UX nightmare, so much clicking that the user is coerced into doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/5353ntuf/6/)**.

You should add an event click on the both buttons `Yes` and `No`, so give them a common class , e.g `confirm` class:

```
<input type="button" class='confirm' value="Yes" />
<input type="button" class='confirm' value="No" />
```

Then add a condition to check which action you're going to perform, like :

```
//Confirm buttons
$("body").on("click", ".confirm", function() {
  $(".popup").hide();

  if ($(this).val() == 'No') 
  {
    $('form input').val(""); //Reset form
  } else {
    $(".seconddiv,.slidethis").hide();
    $(".firstdiv,.button").show();
    $(".wrapper").css("display", "inline-block");
  }
});
```

```js
//slide open the main panel
$(".button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  $(".slidethis").fadeIn(800).css("display", "inline-block");
  $(".wrapper").css("display", "block");
});

$(".seconddiv").hide();
//forstdiv click 
$(".firstdiv").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(".seconddiv").show();
});

//Close button 
$(".close_icon").click(function() {
  $(".popup").show();
});

//Confirm buttons
$("body").on("click", ".confirm", function() {
  $(".popup").hide();

  if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
    $('form input').val("");
  } else {
    $(".seconddiv,.slidethis").hide();
    $(".firstdiv,.button").show();
    $(".wrapper").css("display", "inline-block");
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #9ac366;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headcard {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3% 30px;
  float: left;
}

.slidethis {
  background: #b67fd8;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 70%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  height: 228px;
  display: none;
  position: relative
}

.firstdiv,
.seconddiv {
  width: 200px;
  border: #888 solid 2px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.close_icon {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="headcard">
    <h4>Brand Name</h4>
    <a href="#" class="button">Join Now </a>
  </div>

  <!--this is hidden by default-->
  <div class="slidethis">

    <div class="firstdiv">
      Click here to open the form
    </div>

    <div class="seconddiv">
      <form>
        <a href="#" class="close_icon">X</a>
        <input placeholder="name" />
        <input placeholder="email" />
      </form>
      <!--close pop up-->
      <div class="popup">
        Closing will clear the form data. Do you want ot close?
        <br/>
        <input type="button" class='confirm' value="Yes" />
        <input type="button" class='confirm' value="No" />
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this code should do it. It's about reversing your steps:

```
$("input[value=Yes]").click(function(){
    //reset - reverse all the steps
    $(".button").show();
    $(".slidethis").fadeOut(800).css("display","none");
    $(".wrapper").css("display","inline-block");
    $(".popup").hide();
    $(".seconddiv").hide();
    $(".firstdiv").show();
});


$("input[value=No]").click(function(){
   $(".popup").hide();

});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5353ntuf/5/

Comment: This is very much manual isn't it? Is there any way to unbind the initial click action of `join now` text?

Comment: There is no auto reverse the steps of a click action if that is what you mean with unbind!